# CakePHP - Custom validation for linked model only in certain parent models

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a generic Image model that is linked to by other models that need to have images attached.  In most places the image is not required and we have fallbacks in case there is no image uploaded, but in a few particular cases I need to force the upload of an image for the form to validate, but I'm not sure how to validate that through another model.  For instance, my model is something like this:

```
class Person extends AppModel
{
   public $belongsTo = array(
      'Image' => array(
         'className' => 'Image',
         'foreignKey' => 'image_id',
         'type' => 'LEFT',
      )
  );

  public $validate = array(
     ...
  );
}
```

The `Person` model contains some text fields that folks have to enter as well as a `redirect_url` field.  If a redirect is set the page logic will skip trying to load anything and will redirect directly to that URL.  But, if it is *not* set then a bunch of other fields are required.  I've got this working properly using a custom validation method in my `Person` model, but `image_id` field is not explicitly checked by the `Person` model since it is just a pointer to the `Image` model.

Can I somehow add a custom/dynamic validation rule to `Image` in this instance to have it check if `Person.redirect_url` is set?  The only thing I can figure to do is to add this to my `beforeSave()` and basically manually check it using `$this->data` but I'd like to do this the "right" way if it's possible, hooking into the Validation class.

I tried a few variations on using something like this, with no luck thus far:

`$this->Person->Image->validate['id']=array(...);`

**Edit:**

Here is what I've tried doing, which kind of works:

```
public function beforeValidate($options=array()) {
    parent::beforeValidate($options);

    if(empty($this->data['redirect_url'])) {
        if (!isset($this->data['Image']['filepath']) {
            $this->invalidate('Image.filepath', 'Custom error message.');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This lets me invalidate the field without having to add extra code elsewhere, but when printing out the form field on the front end, I end up getting a generic "This file is required" error instead of my "Custom error message".  I think this might be because file uploads are handled by a plugin that spirits them away to S3 instead of the local filesystem and it's getting overridden somewhere up the chain.

Comment: by default make that field is required.. Based on Model.. before validating just unset that validation of that fields

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint Thanks, that sounds reasonable enough, although a bit of a pain.  I was hoping to set it in this one instance where I need it instead of unsetting it across the half dozen or so where I don't need it.